# How To Delete Record From dba_audit_trail in Oracle 11gR2

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, oracle-11g, delete, audit

I want to delete records older than one month from AUD$ table, but I have to do this on dba_audit_trail, because I have to do this job according dba_audit_trail's timestamp. I can't find any clear solution for it.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE CU
AS
BEGIN
   execute immediate 'delete from SYS.AUD$ where TIMESTAMP > SYSDATE - 30;
END;
/





BEGIN
  DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB (
   job_name           =>  'CLEANUP_AUDIT',
   job_type           =>  'STORED_PROCEDURE',
   job_action         =>  'BEGIN CU(); END;',
   start_date         =>  'I will set it after.',
   repeat_interval    =>  'I will set it after.',
   enabled            =>  'TRUE',
   comments           =>  'I will set it after.');
END;
/
```

Or can I delete on dba_audit_trail directly?

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DBMS_AUDIT_MGMT](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/appdev.112/e16760/d_audit_mgmt.htm)

First execute `INIT_CLEANUP`, that you need to use only once.
Next execute `CREATE_PURGE_JOB` with `use_last_arch_timestamp => true`, which creates the scheduled job for cleaning the audit trail, also need to use only once.
Finally you need to take care of advancing the last archive timestamp with `SET_LAST_ARCHIVE_TIMESTAMP`, which you can simply schedule and set it to `sysdate-30`, or call it as part of your archiving process and set it to the timestamp of last archival, if you use any.

It is also a good idea to create a dedicated tablespace to your audit trail and place it there with `SET_AUDIT_TRAIL_LOCATION`.