# Oracle Delete From a View

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, view, delete, audit

I need to compile below query:

```
delete from dba_audit_trail where TIMESTAMP > SYSDATE - 30;
```

Comment: Why do you have to delete records from the view and can't use the system tables?

Comment: Why are they not comfortable for this operation? You are going to need to give a more clear reasoning why you can do something with the view but not the exact same thing with the source tables.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How To Delete Record From dba\_audit\_trail in Oracle 11gR2](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/265944/how-to-delete-record-from-dba-audit-trail-in-oracle-11gr2)

Comment: I think [DBMS_AUDIT_MGMT.CLEAN_AUDIT_TRAIL](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_audit_mgmt.htm#ARPLS65410) is the right way of doing this.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot. You need to have SYSDBA privilege on the database.

SYSDBA doest not allow to delete from DBA_AUDIT_TRAIL view but it allows to use DBMS_AUDIT_MGMT which is the right way to purge the audit trail.